# How does one protect themselves against XSS attacks while simultaneously displaying characters as users expect to see them?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, xss, owasp

Right now I am escaping all user input :

```
ERB::Util.html_escape_once("Netflix & Chill")
> "Netflix &amp; Chill"
```

Now all my XSS attack worries are gone. However, my end users would not expect this string.

What is the best practice to both protect myself against XSS attacks yet display common use cases of the ampersand ( & ), as well any what we would expect in urls ( `/`, `?`, `&`, `=` )

One hypothesis I've had is that sites like stackoverflow.com probably `.unescape` encoded characters after they've made their way to the View. But I'm not sure if this is accurate or a common practice.

Comment: Exactly where is it rendered incorrectly? The whole point is, it shouldn't be from the user's perspective. For example `&amp;` would just be an & in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sanitizer

```
text = %{
  <span class="text"> Netflix & Chill </span>
}
<%= sanitize text, tags: %w(span), attributes: %w(class) %>
```

Where tags are allowed html tags and attributes are html tag attributes allowed.

Comment: Note that this is a risky (not at all robust), and largely unnecessary solution against xss. This kind of sanitization is usually only necessary when legitimate user input is also html, which is not the asker's usecase as far as I could understand.

Comment: @GaborLengyel how can we do xss without html?

Comment: Usually user input is not meant to be html, that's the point: you encode output, ie. replace say < with &gt;, because it will look the same in the browser, but &gt; is usually not useful for xss. The thing you mention in your answer (sanitization) is necessary when user input is legitimately html, like for example the contents of a wysiwyg html editor (html code) being posted to the application. You can't encode that, because the user expects to see the formatted html he entered - so sanitization remains. If this is not the case, output encoding is way more robust and secure.